# iTunes Connect - Company / Individual Bank Account

Tags: ios, ios4, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We are in a plan to get developer license in order to deploy one our application in APP STORE which involves iTunes Connect integration too.

We have planned to get a developer license in individual name instead of company name since our company name does not matches with the APPLE Terms.

Hence we wanted to know that, at the time of integration with iTunes, can we provide our company bank account details or do we need to provide only the developer license holders account details.

Please share the URL which states this kind of information

Comment: This is NOT the appropriate place to ask this.  This site is for programming questions.  This is a question for Apple customer service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind, that when enrolling as an individual, you won't be able to publish an app under your company's name:

> > **Can I enroll as an individual and have my company appear as the “Seller Name” on the App Store?**
> >
> > No. To have your company name appear as the “Seller Name” on the App Store, your company must be recognized as a legal entity and you must be enrolled as a company/organization. If you are a sole proprietor you must join as an individual and your legal name will appear as the "Seller Name".
> >
> > If you have enrolled as an individual and need to convert your individual account to a company account, please contact us.

source: https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html